# ERROR: column "tickets.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 9 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm'
            WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN '3pm-9pm'
            WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 21 AND 9 THEN '9pm-3am' END "time window",
      COUNT(*)
FROM tickets
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm'
            WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN '3pm-9pm'
            WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 21 AND 9 THEN '9pm-3am' END
```

same query will work if we remove  WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 21 AND 9 THEN '9pm-3am' from both side.

error message:-

```
ERROR:  column "tickets.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 9 AND ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the query that calculates the time window in a derived table for convenience, then group on that

```
select "time window", count(*)
from (
  SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 9 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm'
              WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN '3pm-9pm'
              WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 21 AND 9 THEN '9pm-3am' 
         END "time window"
  FROM tickets
)
GROUP BY  "time window";
```

---

Unrelated to the error message you get, but:

The expression `date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 21 AND 9`is not going to work as you expect it - the between operator requires the lower bound to be smaller than the upper bound. But as your other two expressions already cover the remaining time ranges you can replace that with `ELSE '9pm-3am'`

Your BETWEEN logic is flawed anyway, because a ticket created at e.g. 15:10 will bet counted twice (for '9am-3pm' and for '3pm-9pm') as BETWEEN *includes* both edges - but that is an entirely new question.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking--it's too confusing to re-type a complex `CASE` statement as part of a `GROUP BY` -- stick it in a sub-table and reference by alias!

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at your code.  The thing being selected and the thing being grouped by are not the same thing:

```
BETWEEN 9 AND 15

BETWEEN 3 AND 15
```

Fix that, and it will work.  (Although not correctly, for the reasons already described).

> same query will work if we remove WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 21 AND 9 THEN '9pm-3am' from both side.

Only if you fix the real problem at the same time as you do that.